# User.Identity.Name is null after federated Azure AD login with aspnetcore 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, claims-based-identity, httpcontext

I've followed AzureAD aspnetcore sample as closely as possible to try and implement Azure AD authentication in our aspnetcore 2.2 webapp.  I am able to login successfully using Azure AD.  However, the user's name is not being displayed AFTER login.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp

This value should be read in the view from the User.Identity.Name property.

[image: User.Identity.Name]

On further inspection, I can see that the principal claims are being correctly returned to the application.  However, for some reason the HttpContext.User object is not correctly populated.  I don't know why this is happening.  When I look at the same value from the sample above, HttpContext is correctly set.  For clarification, I have implemented OnSecurityTokenValidated handler and I use this context:

[image: context]

As can be seen, userPrincipal has the claims as expected.

[image: userPrincipal]

However, the httpContext has no claims. Also User.Identity.Name therefore is null:

[image: httoContext]

I've tried to carry out a manual signin, but that doesn't work either:

```
private async Task SignInUser(TokenValidatedContext tokenValidatedContext)
{
    var httpContext = tokenValidatedContext.HttpContext;
    var userPrincipal = tokenValidatedContext.Principal;

    await httpContext.SignOutAsync(AppSettings.CookieName);
    await httpContext.SignInAsync(AppSettings.CookieName, userPrincipal,
      new AuthenticationProperties
      {
          ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
          IsPersistent = false,
          AllowRefresh = false
      });
}
```

**Update**

[image: name]

I am setting the NameClaimType as shown above.  The NameClaimType is set in Configure

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 & aspnetcore 2.2 libraries.  I've upgraded Microsoft.Identity.Client to 2.7

Comment: can you posrt the token that b2c send back ? it may not contain the name ...

Comment: Hi Thomas, i know the principal (of type ClaimsPrincipal) does contain all the data required. It has about 14 claims, including given name, name and surname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got the answer to this, although it leads to new questions.

Basically, our code uses Identity as well as AzureADB2C.  The Identity is conflicting with the AzureADB2C login process.  Login is successful and the token is being returned, but on return it is somehow being erased by Identity.

This is the code that I have in Startup.cs:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options))
            .AddCookie();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = ctx => new ValidationProblemDetailsResult();
        });

        services.AddOptions();

        ConfigureMvc(services);

        // Add Identity services to the services container.
        services.SetupIdentity();
```

SetupIdentity is an extension method that contains the following:

```
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(o => {
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddUserStore<UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, ApplicationContext, Guid>>()
            .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<ApplicationRole, ApplicationContext, Guid>>();
```

The idea is that AAD will be used for authentication, and local Identity roles will be used for giving the user various permissions on the app.  Based on this issue, looks like we will have to rethink our security.

The question is, can AAD and Identity really not be used together?  I'd want a scenario where a user id from AAD is returned, stored in local sql, and then this user id used in the local database to connect the user to variable entities.  If AAD and Identity can't be used together, what is the alternative? I.e. what's the best way to connect an AAD user to a local database? Can anyone point me to some MS articles that discuss this?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this? I have the same problem but with an ASP.NET MVC v5 application

Comment: I am also facing similar problem with classic asp. Net, I can successfully login using azure ad, claims are returned properly, buy user. Identify is null and hence can't use role based folders, that throws error saying unauthorized entry! Is there any solution?

Answer (score 7):

Do you set the `NameClaimType` in `OpenIdConnectOptions` configuration:

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name" };
```

To test the scenario ,  i create a new asp.net core 2.2 application with default MVC template :

1. Install Microsoft.Identity.Client version 2.7
2. Copy the `MSALSessionCache`,`AzureAdB2COptions`,`OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup`from the code sample
3. Update `Startup.cs`and `appsettings.json` based on code sample's configuration .

I haven't create my own application & Api , just use `fabrikamb2c`domain as code sample provides , even though some method is obsolete in .net core 2.2 , for example ,`cache.HasStateChanged` . The authecation still works and get correct name with `User.Identity.Name` , `HttpContext.User.Claims` also be set :

[image]

You might provide more detiails to help reproduce your issue .

Comment: Thanks Nan.  yes, I am setting NameClaimType as shown in my update.  So the issue is that I have copied the code you mentioned exactly from that sample.  However, I have updated to netcore 2.2.  I'm going to upgrade Microsoft.Identity.Client to 2.7 and see if that works.